# How do I count number of a value of a variable given a condition of other variables

Tags: r

I have a data set and I want to count number of times that `GB = 0` when `Time =1`.

```
Time       GB
1          300
2          500
1          0
2          200
1          0
```

Expected result is no rows `GB = 0` when `Time = 1` is 2

Comment: `sum(with(df, Time == 1 & GB == 0))` or `nrow(subset(df, Time == 1 & GB == 0))`

Comment: Great. Thank you. Sorry if my question is too silly.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple ways to do this

```
sum(with(df, Time == 1 & GB == 0))
#[1] 2
```

With `subset`

```
nrow(subset(df, Time == 1 & GB == 0))
```

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(Time == 1 & GB == 0) %>% nrow()
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R approach:

```
# check for data where df$GB = 0 & df$Time=1 and count the length    
nrow(df[df$GB==0 & df$Time==1,])
```

Output:

```
[1] 2
```

**OR**

```
table(df[df$GB==0 & df$Time==1,])
```

Output:

```
    GB
Time 0
   1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `summarise` from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

dat1 %>% 
  summarise(result = sum(GB == 0 & Time == 1))
```

which gives:

```
#  result
#1      2
```

and the data:

```
dat1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="
Time       GB
1          300
2          500
1          0
2          200
1          0 
                 ")
```